# How to cancel wait-event by Ctrl-C instead of cancelling whole script in powershell

Tags: powershell, event-handling

I am using Event related command in powershell, and when I register a object event and wait for it, my script will be paused by the `wait-event` call.

Based on the documentation,

```
The Wait-Event cmdlet suspends execution of a script or 
function until a particular event is raised. Execution 
resumes when the event is detected. 
To cancel the wait, press CTRL+C.
```

But what I found is, when I press Ctrl-C in powershell console, the whole script is ended instead of `wait-event` call, which I thought the `wait-event` call maybe return with $null value.

I don't know if something wrong in my understanding, so hope anyone could share more idea on it.

```ps
$port = New-Object System.IO.Ports.SerialPort COM5,115200,None,8,One
$port.Open()
$subscription = Register-ObjectEvent -InputObject $port -EventName DataReceived -SourceIdentifier "DataReceived"
while($true)
{
    $event = Wait-Event -SourceIdentifier "DataReceived"
    #
    # So how can I check if user press the Control-C to cancel wait-event
    #
    [System.IO.Ports.SerialPort]$sp = $event.Sender;
    $line = $sp.ReadExisting();
    Write-Host $event.EventIdentifier;
    Write-Host $line;

    Remove-Event -EventIdentifier $event.EventIdentifier;
}

Unregister-Event -SourceIdentifier "DataReceived"
$port.Close()
```

--EDIT---

Thanks for the answer, but I want to point out some known solution which I already tried.

```ps
[console]::TreatControlCAsInput = $true
if ([console]::KeyAvailable)
{
    $key = [system.console]::readkey($true)
    if (($key.modifiers -band [consolemodifiers]"control") -and ($key.key -eq "C"))
    {
      "Terminating..."
      break
    }
}
```

This is a good way to resolve the common `Control-C` scenario, but the problem is my application is paused by `wait-event` call, so I have no change to check the key input.

Especially, when I enable Ctrl C for console via `[console]::TreatControlCAsInput = $true`, Control-C will not be able to cancel `Wait-Event` any more, that is also a problem here.

Here is a good example, which you can try ( I rewrite a usable one for someone testing  ):

```ps
$timer = New-Object System.Timers.Timer

[Console]::TreatControlCAsInput = $true;

$subscription = Register-ObjectEvent -InputObject $timer -EventName Elapsed -SourceIdentifier "TimeElapsed"
$event = Wait-Event -SourceIdentifier "DataReceived"
Write-Host "User Cancelled"
Unregister-Event -SubscriptionId $subscription.Id
```

You can run this script, with and without `[Console]::....` to test.

Answer (score 1):

You might have to call `[console]::TreatControlCAsInput = $true` to tell [that (Ctrl+C) is treated as ordinary input](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.console.treatcontrolcasinput(v=vs.110).aspx) and use statements like those in your loop:

```
if ([console]::KeyAvailable)
{
    $key = [system.console]::readkey($true)
    if (($key.modifiers -band [consolemodifiers]"control") -and ($key.key -eq "C"))
    {
      "Terminating..."
      break
    }
}
```

Comment: I try this before my post which I found from google. The problem is, when I enable `[console]::TreatControlCAsInput = $true`, the Wait-Event will not cancel any more.

Answer (score 1):

Wait-Event isn't handling Ctrl+C, the PowerShell host (console host) handles Ctrl+C by stopping your script.

You can specify a timeout with Wait-Event and check for a key press after the time out.  Try the following:

```
$timer = New-Object System.Timers.Timer
$subscription = Register-ObjectEvent -InputObject $timer -EventName Elapsed -SourceIdentifier TimeElapsed

try
{
    $oldTreatControlCAsInput = [Console]::TreatControlCAsInput
    [Console]::TreatControlCAsInput = $true

    Write-Host -NoNewline "Waiting for event "
    do
    {
        $event = Wait-Event -SourceIdentifier DataReceived -Timeout 2
        if ($null -eq $event -and [Console]::KeyAvailable)
        {
            $key = [Console]::ReadKey($true)
            if ($key.KeyChar -eq 3)
            {
                Write-Host "Cancelled"
                break
            }
        }
        Write-Host -NoNewline "."
    } while ($null -eq $event)
}
finally
{
    [Console]::TreatControlCAsInput = $oldTreatControlCAsInput
    Unregister-Event -SourceIdentifier TimeElapsed
}
```

The smallest timeout is 1 second so you may see a short lag between Ctrl+C and when the loop stops.

Comment: I never think this way, but it indeed a workaround. I like it as a good way to handle this scenario currently for my code. But I may expect a perfect solution if possible, so I raise it but without as an accept answer. Thanks so much ;-)